# How to upgrade the private key used to sign a android app on google play store?

Tags: android, apk, code-signing

I want to change the private key used to sign my application for android google play store. It is possible to do it in a way that will not impact the users?

For what i understand, the only way to do that is to publish a second application with a different name and ask user that start my application to install the second one. but doing so will be a pain for the users.

My main issue is that the private key is no longer considered secure (it is a RSA key with length of 1024).

Comment: i use my own key

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can refer to the official page:
https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing.html

I made summary about your problem:

if you use:

1. google play app signing=> contact google to use new private key
2. your own key=> It's impossible to achieve what you want!

Hope this post help you!!